# Issues setting up jdk9 in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans

I have jdk9 properly installed and i'm able to use it with intellij.
In netbeans if i go to **tools > java platforms > add platform > java standard edition > jdk-9** I have a window with *Platform Name* , *Platform Sources* and *Platform Javadoc* . In platform name i have prefilled *JDK 9* , the other 2 are blank. If i finish i have no classes, sources or javadoc and i can't use it. I then tried to *add jar/forlder* under sources and adding **jdk-9\lib\src.zip** since looking at it it showed all the standard modules, but still i have empty classes and i cannot use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Netbeans 9 nightly builds (http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) to get proper support for JDK 9.

This is generally true for later versions of Java with Netbeans and especially true because of the fundamental modularisation of the JDK in 9.